# Why do the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem and The Principle of Superposition not contradict each other?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have a question regarding the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem and The Principle of Superposition, which my book (Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems) defines in the following ways:

> **Existence and Uniqueness Theorem**
>
> Consider the initial value problem
> $$y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y = g(t), \qquad y(t_0) = y_0, \qquad y'(t_0) = y'_0$$
> where $p$, $q$, and $g$ are continuous on an open interval $I$ that contains the point $t_0$. Then, there is exactly one solution $y = \phi(t)$ of this problem, and the solution exists throughout the interval $I$.
>
> **Principle of Superposition**
>
> If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions of the differential equation $y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y = 0$, then the linear combination $c_1 y_1 + c_2 y_2$ is also a solution for any values of the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

From the existence and uniqueness theorem, we know there is only one equation $y = \phi(t)$ that satisfies the equation $y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y = 0$. From the principle of superposition, we know that $y = c\phi(t)$ is also a solution. How is this possible? Is it because the existence and uniqueness theorem is for particular solutions, where as the principle of superposition is for general solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Existence and Uniqueness Theorem **doesn't say** that there is only one function $y = \phi(t)$ satisfying the equation $y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y = 0$. In fact, the number of solutions for this equation is infinite.

Existence and Uniqueness Theorem **says** that there is only one function $y = \phi(t)$ **satisfying simultaneously** the equation $y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y = 0$ **and** the initial conditions $y(t_0) = y_0$, $y'(t_0) = y'_0$.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I suspected, but I wanted to confirm my suspicions.

Comment: @Birdman2246 You are welcome! In short: they talk about different things. Principle of Superposition talks about homogeneous equations but Existence and Uniqueness Theorem talks about initial value problems.

Answer (score 2):

From the existence and uniqueness theorem, we know that given $y_0$ and $y'_0$, there is only one solution $y = \phi(t)$ (depending on $y_0$ and $y'_0$) of the equation $y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y = 0$ satisfying $y(t_0) = y_0$ and $y'(t_0) = y'_0$.

But when you make linear combinations of solutions you change their values $y_0$ and $y'_0$.